# New-TimeSpan: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell (general new to coding). What I am trying to do is: A user should be able to input a date. Powershell should echo the amount of days left till next year's December 6th.

Example: Input is 20/01/2017 and the output should be the amount of days left till 06/12/2018.

It works completely fine when I do `$days = New-TimeSpan -End (Get-Date -Year $inputdate3 -Month 12 -day 6)` but I want to replace this cmdlet with my string.

My code is:

```
$inputdate = Read-Host "Please enter the current date [DD/MM/YYYY] :"
$inputdate = [DateTime]::Parse($inputdate)
$inputdate2 = $inputdate.AddYears(1)
$inputdate3 = $inputdate2.Year

$days = New-TimeSpan -Start $inputdate -End $inputdate3 -Month 12 -Day 6 | ForEach-Object {$_.days}

echo "$days"
```

But I get this error:

> New-TimeSpan : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified
>   named parameters. At C:\Users\Asli\Desktop\O2P2_Version1_2.ps1:96
>   char:13
>   +     $days = New-TimeSpan -Start $inputdate -End $inputdate3 -Month 12 ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand

Comment: This is a parameter set issue. If you use `-Start` and `-End`, you cannot use `-Month` and `-Day` in the same command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) notes in a comment, **your problem is one of using *incompatible parameters***:

PowerShell groups parameters that can be used together with a given command into so-called *parameter sets*.

Only parameters all belonging to *one* of the parameter sets can be used together in a given invocation of a command.

In your case, `-Start` and `-Month`, for instance, belong to *different* parameter sets, which prompted the error you saw.

The simplest way to **inspect a command's parameter sets** is to use **`Get-Command -Syntax`** (you could also just pass `-?` to show the syntax diagram, in the context of concise command-line help, or `Get-Help`, in the context of richer help; a command's [online help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan) shows parameter sets too):

```
PS> Get-Command -Syntax New-TimeSpan

New-TimeSpan [[-Start] <datetime>] [[-End] <datetime>] [<CommonParameters>]

New-TimeSpan [-Days <int>] [-Hours <int>] [-Minutes <int>] [-Seconds <int>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

As you can see, there are 2 parameter sets: `-Start` and `-End` form one, and `-Days`, `-Hours`, `-Minutes` and `-Seconds` the other.

---

Note that **you don't need to use `New-TimeStamp` at all, because subtracting two `[datetime]` instances implicitly yields a `[timespan]` instance** that represent the time span (difference) between the two dates.

Therefore, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
$inputDate = [datetime]::Parse((Read-Host "Please enter a start date [DD/MM/YYYY]"))

$refDate = Get-Date -Day 6 -Month 12 -Year ($inputDate.Year + 1) 

$days = ($refDate - $inputDate).Days
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Peony; my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$startDate = Read-Host "Please enter the current date [DD/MM/YYYY] :"
$startDate = [DateTime]::Parse($startDate)

$endDate = Get-Date -Year ($startDate.Year + 1) -Month 12 -Day 6

$days = (New-TimeSpan –Start $startDate –End $endDate).Days
$days
```